# Keplergl Filters : multiple attributes per field?

Tags: kepler.gl

Is the keplergl filter system able to parse arrays with multiple categories ?
For example a point representing a industrial building who would have all of thoses attributes in the same field ["Non-hazardous waste", "Hazardous waste", "Inert waste"]

if not is there a way to inject the filter action or the data parsing action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature does not seem to be implemented yet

Kepler's data-processor parses Arrays and Objects as it is GeoJson

[processors/data-processor.js](https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/blob/master/src/processors/data-processor.js) line 399

```
  switch (aType) {
case DATE:
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.date;
case TIME:
case DATETIME:
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.timestamp;
case FLOAT:
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.real;
case INT:
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.integer;
case BOOLEAN:
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.boolean;
case GEOMETRY:
case GEOMETRY_FROM_STRING:
case PAIR_GEOMETRY_FROM_STRING:
case ARRAY:
case OBJECT:
  // TODO: create a new data type for objects and arrays
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.geojson;
case NUMBER:
case STRING:
case ZIPCODE:
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.string;
default:
  globalConsole.warn(`Unsupported analyzer type: ${aType}`);
  return ALL_FIELD_TYPES.string;
}
```